# Decay formula problem

Tags: calculus

I have the problem,

A radioactive substance has a half-life of $10$ days. The initial amount of the 
substance is $100$ milligrams. 
(a) Determine the decay rate of the substance. 
(b) How much of the substance is left after $5$ days? 
(c) How long does it take for the substance to decay to $1$0 percent of its 
original amount?

So the decay formula is $A = A_0\cdot (\frac12)^{t/h}$. $h = 10$, $t = ?$ , $A_0 = 100$

How am I suppose to handle this if I don't have a value for A? I'm solving for t in part (a), correct?

Comment: I think that half life means that A=5 if Ao was 100...

Comment: Usually one takes $A(t) = A_0 e^{-t/h}$.

Comment: @user3032755  $A_{\circ}$ is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decay formula is $A(t) = A_0 2^{-\lambda t}$ with $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{h}$ the decay rate.

1. Half-time $t_{1/2}$ being the time such that $A(t_{1/2}) = \dfrac{A_0}{2}$ one has :
   \begin{align}
   A(t_{1/2}) = \dfrac{A_0}{2} &\Leftrightarrow A_0 2^{-\lambda t_{1/2}} = \dfrac{A_0}{2}\\
   &\Leftrightarrow \lambda t_{1/2} = 1\\
   &\Leftrightarrow \lambda = \dfrac{1}{t_{1/2}}\\
   \end{align}
   Or $t_{1/2} = 10\ d$, hence $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{10}=0.1\ d^{-1}$.
2. The amount of matter after $5$ days is $A_0 2^{-5\lambda} = \dfrac{A_0}{\sqrt 2} = \dfrac{100}{\sqrt 2} \approx 70.71\ mg$.
3. Let $t_{1/10}$ such that $A(t_{1/10}) = \dfrac{A_0}{10}$.
   \begin{align}
   A(t_{1/10}) = \dfrac{A_0}{10} &\Leftrightarrow A_0 2^{-\lambda t_{1/10}} = \dfrac{A_0}{10}\\
   &\Leftrightarrow \lambda t_{1/10} = \log_2 10\\
   &\Leftrightarrow t_{1/10} = t_{1/2}\log_2 10
   \end{align}
   Since $t_{1/2} = 10\ d$ one has $t_{1/10} = 10 \log_2 10\approx 33.22\ d$.